CDF for the distance of a point chosen uniformly inside a square to its boundary
I have the following problem and I want to derive the cumulative distribution function (CDF) $F_X(x)$ for a random variable $X$.
Problem:
A point is chosen at random and uniformly inside a square of dimension $10 \times 10$. Let $X$ be the distance between the chosen point and the boundary of the square.

How can I obtain the cumulative distribution function $F_X(x)$ of $X$?
What is the probability density function $f_X(x)$ of $X$?

Understanding so far:

The variable $X$ can vary from $0$ (point on the boundary) to $5$ (point at the center of the square).


Hint : $1-F_X(x)=P(X>x)$ is a ratio of areas : area(inscribed square with side $(10-2x)$/area(big square). Then differentiate for getting $f_X(x)$

We may suppose the square is centered at the origin.
Take any $0\leq c\leq 5$. Then, the set of points on the $10\times 10$ square with distance to the boundary bigger than or equal to $c$ is a (filled) square with vertices $$(5-c,5-c), \,(5-c,c-5),\, (c-5,c-5),\, (c-5,5-c) $$
The area of this square is $(10-2c)^2$. Given that the area of the big square is $100$, we have $$F_X(c)=\Pr(X\leq c)=1-\Pr(X\geq c)=1-\dfrac{(10-2c)^2}{100}, \, 0\leq c\leq 5$$
The density function is obtained by differentiating this cdf and is equal to $$f_X(c)=\dfrac{10-2c}{25}, \,0\leq c\leq 5$$

Why do we define this smaller square? I don't see its relation to any given point

@MouhKramo We want the probability that $X\leq c$. In this kind of problems, this probability is defined as the area of the region that satisfies $X\leq c$ divided by the total area. In this case, the region such that $X>c$ is that smaller square.

Ah yes, it's clear now it is similar to the problem of throwing a dart at a target containing three circles with different points.
